# Isomorphic strings in LeetCode

Tags: c#, c++, performance, programming-challenge, array

I solved [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/isomorphic-strings/) problem:

> Given two strings s and t, determine if they are isomorphic.
>
> Two strings are isomorphic if the characters in s can be replaced to
>   get t.
>
> All occurrences of a character must be replaced with another character
>   while preserving the order of characters. No two characters may map to
>   the same character but a character may map to itself.

**For example:**

> Given "egg", "add", return true.
>
> Given "foo", "bar", return false.
>
> Given "paper", "title", return true.

**Note:**

> You may assume both s and t have the same length.

The code in C# on average took around **109ms** to execute, which is pretty slow compared to the C++ version of the same algorithm, which executes in under **6ms**. Although, the fastest C# solution for this problem is around **100ms**.

```
public class Solution {
    public bool IsIsomorphic(string s, string t) {
            int[] map = Enumerable.Repeat(-1, 175).ToArray();
            bool[] marked = Enumerable.Repeat(false, 175).ToArray();
            for(int i=0; i<s.Length; ++i)
            {
                if (map[s[i]] ==  -1) // Unvisited 
                {
                    if (marked[t[i]]) // Already has a mapping
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

                    marked[t[i]] = true;

                    map[s[i]] = t[i];
                }
                else if(map[s[i]] != t[i])
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
    }
}
```

Optimizations I had done:

- Converted `List<T>` to `array` after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454916/performance-of-arrays-vs-lists)
- Changed `foreach` to a plain `for` loop that helped remove another index variable for iterating over string `t`

Can you suggest any better way to squeeze some performance from the C# implementation?

And from the FAQ section of LeetCode I could see that C# uses mono 4.2.1 and C++ uses g++ 5.4.0.

I'm attaching the C++ solution as well just for reference:

```
#define MAX_CHARS 175
class Solution {
public:
    bool isIsomorphic(string str1, string str2) {
    bool marked[MAX_CHARS] = {false};

    // To store mapping of every character from str1 to
    // that of str2. Initialize all entries of map as -1.
    int map[MAX_CHARS];
    memset(map, -1, sizeof(map));

    // Process all characters one by on
    for (int i = 0; i < str1.size(); i++)
    {
        // If current character of str1 is seen first
        // time in it.
        if (map[str1[i]] == -1)
        {
            // If current character of str2 is already
            // seen, one to one mapping not possible
            if (marked[str2[i]] == true)
                return false;

            // Mark current character of str2 as visited
            marked[str2[i]] = true;

            // Store mapping of current characters
            map[str1[i]] = str2[i];
        }

        // If this is not first appearance of current
        // character in str1, then check if previous
        // appearance mapped to same character of str2
        else if (map[str1[i]] != str2[i])
            return false;
    }

    return true;

    }
};
```

Comment: My execution of `Console.WriteLine(IsIsomorphic("paper","title"));` took less than 10 ms due to VS 2015 Diagnostic Tools on Windows 10 64 bit Core i7-6820HQ 2.7 GHz.

Comment: C# is a JIT language, the first time through is when it compiles to machine code. It is difficult to compare C# to C++ when the method is only called once. I'm willing to bet that it's a much closer implementation if you run it multiple times and even better in release with the debugger detached.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how much runtime you'll save, but you're iterating 175 more times  than you need to here.

> ```
> int[] map = Enumerable.Repeat(-1, 175).ToArray();
> bool[] marked = Enumerable.Repeat(false, 175).ToArray();
> ```

You can replace this with an old fashioned `for` loop and set them both at once.

```
const int maxChars = 175;

int[] map = new int[maxChars];
bool[] marked = new bool[maxChars];

for (var i = 0; i < maxChars; i++)
{
    map[i] = -1; 
    marked[i] = false;
}
```

It's more verbose, but might save you a millisecond or 2.

Comment: There isn't really a good reason to do `Enumerable.Repeat(false, 175)`, by default `bool` is false already, so `bool[] marked = new bool[175];` does the same thing.

Comment: Nice catch @RonBeyer!